# Setting opaque background color on Jetpack Compose Button causes non-uniform coloring (inner rectangle)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-button

I've been having this issue where I need to set an opaque color for the background of a `Button` in Jetpack Compose.

This is the code which I'm dumbed down and tested with:

```
<color name="opaque_button_background">#33FFFFFF</color>

    Button(
        onClick = { },
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp),
        colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
            backgroundColor = colorResource(R.color.opaque_button_background)
        ),
    ) {
        Text(
            text = "Hello"
        )
    }
```

This is what it produces:
[image: button preview]

I'm having a similar problem in the code I'm working with, but not as pronounced as this. Looks like there's a separate background for the content of the button.

Even removing `Text` content inside gives you: [image: button preview without content]

Anyone know what's going on? Looks like the implementation of `Button` doesn't work well with opaque colors?

Comment: You have to convert the semitransparent color to the non transparent one

Comment: Does this mean you can't use transparent colours at all? Or is there some conversion method I'm missing?

Comment: The issue happens because of elevation of the Button and the semitransparent color  used as background. You can't use them in this case

Answer (score -1):

You can use TextButton instead of Button.

```
TextButton(
        onClick = { },
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp),
        colors = ButtonDefaults.textButtonColors(Color(R.color.opaque_button_background),
            Color(R.color.opaque_button_background),
            Color(R.color.opaque_button_background)),
    ) {
        Text(
            text = "Hello", color = Color.Red
        )
    }
```